# CSS address code doesnt appear

Tags: css, line

Hi whats wrong with adress code? Doesnt show dotted line. Everything was ok, but the address code is bad? Maybe something wrong, iam just a newbie so please understand me :)

```css
body {
padding-left: 11em;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: purple;
background-color: #d8da3d }
ul.navbar {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 1em;
width; 9em }
h1 {
font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif }
ul.navbar li {
background: white;
margin: 0.5em 0;
border-right: 1em solid black }
ul.navbar a {
text-decoration: none }
a:link {
color: blue;}
a:visited: }
color: purple }
address {
margin-top: 1em;
padding-top: 1em;
border-top: thin dotted }
```

(EDIT) There is HTML code too

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mano pirmas CSS puslapis</title>

<<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"

</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Site navigation menu -->
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="index.html">Namų puslapis</a>
<li><a href="muiliukai.html">Muiliukai</a>
<li><a href="kainos.html">Kainos</a>
<li><a href="kurmusrasti.html">Kur mus rasti?</a>
</ul>

<!-- Main content -->

<h1> Mano pirmas CSS puslapis<h1>

<p>Sveiki atvykę į Naminių muiliukų svetainę</p>

<p>Šioje svetainėje yra nuotraukų bei kainų sąrašas. Muiliukų pasirinkimas yra išties milžiniškas, tad jei išsirinkai nedelsk - užsisakyk!</p>
 
<p>Vėliau bus dar daugiau! Sekite mus.</p>

<!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite -->
<address>Sukurta 07 Vasario 2015<br>
Vytautas Likas</address>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we have the html side too ?

Comment: You have a syntax error in the CSS file just before the address rule (`a:visited:`) so the browser stops parsing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provided I could see two syntax errors which I pointed out below but otherwise your code looks fine. When testing your code in a browser you can press F12 to bring up the debugger, it might help catch some of these errors for you. I know you said your a newbie but its a good idea to get into good programming habits, formatting your code makes it easier for others to read. Hope this solves your problem.

```
body {
    padding-left: 11em;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: purple;
    background-color: #d8da3d;
}

ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 1em;
    width: 9em;
}
```

You had a semi colon after width instead of a colon

```
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
}

ul.navbar li {
    background: white;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    border-right: 1em solid black;
}

ul.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: blue;
}
```

You had a colon and a closing curly bracket instead of an opening on this line `a:visited: }`

```
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}

address {
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-top: thin dotted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advise, i already have a firebug, i try to use that tool. I hope it will be helpful